# respond with 'js' only if request has errors (otherwise use html)

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form to create Appointment objects, targeting :create method. When the object is created successfully I want the method to respond with html, but if it's not I want to respond with js. 
This is what i did:

```
def create
  appointment = Appointment.new(appointment_params)
  if appointment.save
    redirect_to appointment_path(appointment)
  else
    @errors = appointment.errors
    redirect_to new_appointment_path, format: 'js'
  end
end
```

When `appointment.save` is `true` the application responds properly with an html template. But when it's `false` rails still expects an html template (ignoring the `format: 'js'`):

```
Missing template appointments/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:es], :formats=>[:html],..}
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

PS: form does NOT have remote :true

Comment: When you say "not working", can you explain how you know this?  Please show errors with backtrace, logs, and other information to help figure out what's happening.

Comment: just edited the answer adding more info + error message @Michal Gaskill

Comment: Do you have a file in your app/view/appointments directory named either `new.html.erb` or `new.html.haml`?  You'd also need one named `new.js.erb` or `new.js.haml` for the format: 'js' route.

Comment: i have a new.js.erb file. I dont want a new.html file, i want to handle that action only by ajax.

Comment: Ahhhh... The Ajax bit wasn't included in your question.  The tag didn't make that clear at all.  Knowing it now makes all the difference.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you want to use a Rails-ism to avoid rendering the missing HTML template:

```
def create
  appointment = Appointment.new(appointment_params)
  if appointment.save
    redirect_to appointment_path(appointment) and return
  else
    @errors = appointment.errors
    redirect_to new_appointment_path, format: 'js' and return
  end
end
```

After the `redirect_to` calls, you need to `return` from the function, so that Rails doesn't automatically try to render the HTML template for the action.

Comment: Sorry Michael, but i still get the same error: Missing template appointments/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:es], :formats=>[:html],..}

Comment: Are you using the `and return` new code that I included in my answer?  It has to be on both redirect_to lines

Comment: just in case, i say this again: form does NOT have remote :true

Comment: The `remote: true` option doesn't affect this; it's a client-side option used with unobtrusive javascript to change a form or link to Ajax.  That doesn't get passed to the server, so it wouldn't have an impact on how the controller and renderer works.